# What is the difference between PushPageModel and PushPageModelWithNewNavigation while using FreshMVVM?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, freshmvvm

I need  new navigation page using FreshMVVM .While using the           PushPageModelWithNewNavigation the view size is changed but it is perfect while using PushPageModel. Kindly suggest a solution or explain the difference between the two?

```
public class PageModel : FreshBasePageModel
{
    public Command GoToDoc => new Command(async () => await GoToViewer());
    public Command GoToPage => new Command(async () => await GoToNewMain());

    private async Task GoToViewer()
    {
          await CoreMethods.PushPageModelWithNewNavigation<PdfViewPageModel>(null, true);


    }

    private async Task GoToNewMain()
    {
        await CoreMethods.PushPageModel<PageModel>(null, false, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FreshMvvm `PushPageModelWithNewNavigation` is starting new `NavigationStack` unlike `PushPageModel`. If you use `PushPageModelWithNewNavigation` with `TabbedPage` or `ContentPage`, It would show you new screen without child Tabs & Backarrow on top. But you can have your custom button to close this top page.

As you have method `GoToViewer()`, It would start a new `Page` as viewer without having Tabs or arrow on action bar.